# Is there a new tag for undeline (<u>) in html 5?

Tags: html

In HTML 5 there are new tags. Like for `<b>` you can use `<strong>` tag. But is there any new tag for the `<u>` tag?

Answer (score 1):

No.

Presentation is the job of CSS. The living HTML specification has not introduced any new elements designed purely for presentational effects.

The `<strong>` element is not a new way to make text bold. It gives an element strong emphasis. This just happens to be expressed with a default stylesheet that uses bold for the element in most visual browsers. It also isn't new as it has been around since at least as long as [HTML 2](https://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html-spec/L2index.html#STRONG).

The Living HTML specification hasn't introduced any new elements which have a default styling of being underlined either.

Answer (score 0):

As Quentin said, all design elements of the page are reserved to CSS.

What **HTML** tags do is provide **semantic information** to the page. It basically names what type of thing is present on the page.

Understanding this destinction is important for accessibility and search engine optimisation. If a search engine sees an `<h1>` element it will prioritise it over a `<h2>` element.

This is why even if you want a smaller **main heading**, you shouldn't use any other tag but **`<h1>`**. If you want to make the `<h1>` tag smaller, use CSS.

If you want to underline text you can place the text between `<span>` tags and then style the span tag with CSS like so:

CSS:

```
span {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

HTML:

```
<p>Hello <span>World</span></p>
```

You can also add an id or a class to the span if you are going to use multiple span tags.